# Including javascript file in JSM file

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

I am aware of `Components.utils.import("resource://javascript/xzy.jsm");` as a way to import jsm modules, but, do you know of a way to do a more basic `<script type="application/x-javascript" src="resource://javascript/abc.js" />` type of include within a javascript file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [loadSubScript from mozIJSSubScriptLoader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/mozIJSSubScriptLoader#loadSubScript%28%29).